# .NET Web API | Open ID Connect Authentication Flow

Tags: .net, openid-connect, webapi

I am currently looking at integrating with an external Open ID Connect Provider where I have all of the endpoints which are needed for the flow.

I can successfully get a token and use this directly against the external get user endpoint in order to get the information based on the user, so I know the token and the flow is working.

Once I have this, I need to authenticate it against our Internal API, which is where I am struggling to do the with the flow and I am after some advice.

I have added the Open ID Connect to my .NET 7 Web API with the details from the service which we are integrating with.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "REDACTED";
        options.ClientSecret = "REDACTED";
        options.Authority = "REDACTED";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    });
```

Realistically I want to use the code provided by the external provider to also authenticate against my internal API, however, I don't think this is possible and / or it's not advised so I'm after some advice.

Once I get the token, should I hit my own endpoint with said which performs a request against the external provider which then issues a token from my own API for authentication and use this for all subsequent requests? The only thing then is obviously, the token could become invalid at some point?

I've done this previously using Azure AD authentication which uses that token so it leads me to believe that this is possible. Please let me know if I am on the wrong tracks.

EDIT: Some additional information is this token provided by the OIDC server will also need to be used on subsequent requests to an external API, which means I will need the original access token somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For API's to accept tokens, you should not use AddOpenIdConnect, instead you should use AddJwtBearer instead. You use AddJwtBearer in the client application where the user log in.

Alternatively, you add your own local Identity provider, like IdentityServer in your network, that your internal APIS/Services trusts, like:

[image]

I wrote a blog post about debugging JWtBearer problems [here](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/) if you have trouble getting it to work.